# how to create a list of vectors from names generated by a formula

Tags: r, list

The variables are generated by the following code

```
A <- seq(from = 90, to = 110, by = 1) 
B <- seq(from = 90, to = 120, by = 5) 
C <- seq(from = 100, to = 130, by = 10)
D <- c(130, 140)
E <- 160

Raw_Input <- list("A"= A, "B"= B, "C"= C, "D"=D, "E"= E) # combine into list
```

The result I want is achieved by the following code:

```
list(A, B, C, D, E)
```

But I would like to do is automatically create the list using something such as the following:

```
list(noquote(paste(LETTERS[1:4], collapse=", ", sep="")))
```

But R does not understand the output of this line to be the variables I created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this `str(Raw_Input)`

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Maybe `mget(LETTERS[1:4])`?

Comment: roland, that is it! that is what I wanted. Thanks!If you could suggest better wording to the question, I will make the edit.

Comment: The real answer is, of course, that you shouldn't create these free-floating variables in your global environment. Put them into a list when you create them. Using `mget` just treats the symptom and not the disease.

Comment: I take the point. Thank you. The purpose of this code is to do some testing of the output of a function. So, it is just a temporary thing to scratch around. The final input source will probably be a CSV file.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
my.list = list('A'=A, 'B'=B, 'C'=C, 'D'=C, 'E'=E)
my.list[['A']]
```

You can access them by names.

Comment: ah no, i think i need to rephrase the question )